# Xamarin Forms Google Navigation Drawer

Tags: visual-studio, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

I followed this code to design a basic master detail navigation drawer

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/master-detail-page/

Where can i find examples or samples that will enable me to recreate a sidebar very similar to Google? I am looking for one which also has the settings menu item fixed to the bottom of the navigation drawer. Ideally id like to be able to click on the profile image and navigate to a profile page too.

I would love to find a version of this that i could use with visual studio, this is what im looking for: https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Xamarin.Forms you just have to recreate the page and set it as the Master of the MasterDetailPage.

You can read more about it here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/master-detail-page/

Comment: As i said i have already used this code to design a master detail page, i want to be able to customise it to look like the Google sidebar. With a settings menu fixed to the bottom and a clickable profile picture

Comment: Can you add a picture of what screen you want to replicate? 

You should be able to layout a page with a grid, or even just a ListView where the header is your profile picture with a TapGestureRecognizer.

Comment: Its in the original post but i edited it to show a screenshot @Rui Marinho

Comment: Yeah you can do it all in XF a grid with a Tableview in the 2 row, each item of the TableView should be a ImageCell so you can have icon + name.

About the top header you can have a row and columns with a image full width with  columnspan for the background, and the same row you overlay your other images  and labels. 

Should be easy to achieve it.

Comment: Great, i just started working with Xamarin so its quite new but thanks for the input! Would i be correct in saying for a settings menu item fixed to the bottom of the navigation menu, i would need to use a separate Table view and style it accordingly? (Keep in mind ive used the master detail view template in the original question and my menu is currently in a list view.)

Comment: Yes another tableview

Answer (score 1):

You can have something pretty close to that if you use https://github.com/nativecode-dev/oss-xamarin/. Though it hasn't been updated to the new XF2, it does have a NavigationLayout renderer, and [I fixed the header not showing issue](https://github.com/nativecode-dev/oss-xamarin/issues/54). The sample project has 2 ways to setup your Master Detail Page. You'll have to setup your actual Page navigation separately of course.

Comment: Thanks ill have a look!